# Viber does not detect my contact list on BlueStacks

Tags: viber-messenger, bluestacks

I use BlueStacks.

I installed Viber before importing contact list to BlueStacks. After importing contact list to BlueStacks list, Viber does not sync the contacts.

After importing, I installed Whatsapp. Whatsapp detected the contact list, and showed the list in Whatsapp's friend lists. I installed Line, and it detected the contacts list too.

I re-installed Viber, but it did not the solve problem. The contacts still do not show in Viber.

When I invite a friend to Viber, my contact list not show any number.

What can i do?

Comment: To be honest I'd contact Viber developers and see what they can do.

Answer (score 1):

Viber has not been tested on Bluestacks, as it is not a platform that supports Viber on its  own.

However, in order to have a contact list, Viber syncs to the device on which it is installed. You can try deleting Viber and re-installing to see if it syncs with your contacts. Other than that, there is not much that we can assist with.

Comment: after several days i check and see , viber sync contact numbers that not have country code